# How to get the full name of the method?

Tags: javascript, array.prototype.map

Here is what I tried and what I need to get:

```
function f(obj) {
    console.log(obj.name)  // 'map'
    console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)  // 'ƒ () { [native code] }'

    console.log(/* How to get 'Array.prototype.map'? */);
}

f(Array.prototype.map);
```

Comment: Object property values have no static relationship to any particular object. When you call that function, all it gets is a reference to the built-in `map()` function but *nothing* reveals that the reference to that function was obtained from a property value on the `Array.prototype` object. In other words, the method in no sense has a "full name".

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Maybe there's another way you can accomplish what you're trying to do?

Comment: @KhauriMcClain yes I can live without it, but with it I can simplify my code a little bit. It is about mocking functions for unit testing, I do not want to use existing libraries.